# The parameter in a custom function when using pandas.Series.apply

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a simple pandas Dataframe defined as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    'word':     ['flower', 'mountain', 'ocean', 'universe'],
    'k':        [1, 2, 3, 4]
} )

>>> df
   k      word
0  1    flower
1  2  mountain
2  3     ocean
3  4  universe
```

I want to change df into this ( replace every word with its first k letters )

```
>>> df
   k  word
0  1     f
1  2    mo
2  3   oce
3  4  univ
```

I have an idea to achieve this by using pandas.Series.apply with a custom function

```
def get_first_k_letters( x, k ):
    return x[:k]

df['word'] = df['word'].apply( get_first_k_letters, args=(3,) )

>>> df
   k word
0  1  flo
1  2  mou
2  3  oce
3  4  uni
```

I can easily replace every word with its first 3 letters by setting args=(3,).

But I want to replace every word with its first k letters ( k is not always the same ) and I don't know what is the setting for args in this case.

Could somebody help me? Thanks! ( Other methods without using pandas.Series.apply will also be OK! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider this approach:

```
In [121]: df['word'] = [w[1][:w[0]] for w in df.values]

In [122]: df
Out[122]:
   k  word
0  1     f
1  2    mo
2  3   oce
3  4  univ
```

**Timing:** for 40.000 rows DF:

```
In [123]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [124]: df.shape
Out[124]: (40000, 2)

In [125]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: get_first_k_letters(x['word'], x['k']), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.04 s per loop

In [126]: %timeit [w[1][:w[0]] for w in df.values]
10 loops, best of 3: 52.5 ms per loop

In [127]: 4.04 * 1000 / 52.5
Out[127]: 76.95238095238095
```

Comment: Thank you! You are a python specialist!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df.apply(lambda x: get_first_k_letters(x['word'], x['k']), axis=1)
```

Doing the `apply` with `axis=1` option, yields each row into `x` (of the `lambda`. Giving `axis=0` gives columns, not rows). Giving `x['word']` and `x['k']` to your function yields the correct outcome:

```
0       f
1      mo
2     oce
3    univ
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MaxU hehe, no problem. Your solution is indeed much faster for this specific case, but will not always work :)